# Displaying variable in several locations on HTML page

Tags: javascript, html

I'd like to define a value in one location and display that value in several locations on an HTML page.

The examples I've seen use a div and access its id through javascript (or jQuery).  In that case, I'd like to access several ids since they can't have the same id value.  But doesn't that mean I'd have to define three variables with the same value?

Comment: Your question is unclear, post some code so we can understand.

Comment: No, you would define one variable with the value you want to replace, and then loop through the ids of the elements for which you need to do the replacement. Otherwise, use a class attribute or a custom attribute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use classes instead of ids to select multiple divs and set their contents.

eg. these three divs have unique ids but share the same class:

```
<div id="div1" class="shared_class"></div>
<div id="div2" class="shared_class"></div>
<div id="div3" class="shared_class"></div>
```

You can set their contents at the same time, in jQuery:

```
$('.shared_class').text('blah blah blah');
```

Comment: I don't see that anything is happening.  I've created a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/hbzzS/.

Comment: That works.  But isn't working within my site.  The jQuery reference is mysite.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.8.3.  That should work right?  Is there a way to check if that's a good jquery reference?

Comment: By the way, I'm defining it within <script>...</script>

Comment: Make sure you have a `$(document).ready(function(){});` and add the code there